# Why android:fullBackupOnly default value is false?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

In https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element,

> android:fullBackupOnly
>
> This attribute indicates whether or not to use
>   Auto Backup on devices where it is available. If set to true, then
>   your app performs Auto Backup when installed on a device running
>   Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher. On older devices, your app
>   ignores this attribute and performs Key/Value Backups. The default
>   value is "false".

If the default value is `false`, does that mean all Android version will prefer legacy [**Android Backup Service**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup) over modern [**Android Auto Backup**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup)?

But, according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

> Auto Backup for Apps automatically backs up a user's data from apps
>   that target and run on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later.

Seem like modern **Android Auto Backup** is the default choice. If so, why the default value for `android:fullBackupOnly` is `false`?

Answer (score 4):

The language that is used in documentation is confusing indeed. There are two ways to backup data: Auto-backup and Key-value backup. When you define a BackupAgentHelper in you manifest, you are using Key-value backup.

- `android:fullBackupOnly=true` means that you will always do Auto-backup, even if you have a BackupAgentHelper defined in your manifest.
- `android:fullBackupOnly=false` means that you do Auto-backup if no BackupAgentHelper is defined, and Key-value when a BackupAgentHelper is defined.